# Magento 2 : Create order programmatically with payment

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to create order programmatically with payment by token.

I checked many tutorials but not getting success.

Can anyone please help me to create script for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this --> http://www.blogtreat.com/programmatically-create-new-order-in-magento-2/

Comment: Already tried. It's not with payment.

Comment: what do you mean by "with payment by token" ?

Comment: I want to create order of virtual product by Braintree payment. I saved token in my table. By use this token i want to do payment.

Comment: @Arif can you please help me?

Comment: May I know how you can pass credit card information?

Comment: Get public hash value and save in my table.